# Definition of Uniform Continuity on an LCA group

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I was working on an exercise from Tao's *An Epsilon of Room* to show the existence of Haar measure on an LCA group.  For one of part of the problem we have ($G$ an LCA group, $C_c(G)^+$ denoting the subset of nonnegative not everywhere zero functions in $C_c(G)$):

> Let $\mu$ be a Haar measure on $G$.  Show for every $f \in C_c(G)^+$ and $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $g \in C_c(G)^+$ such that $\int_G f d\mu \ge (f :g) \int_G g d\mu - \epsilon$. (*Hint*: $f$ is uniformly continuous.  Take $g$ to be an approximation to the identity.)

If you want to give the solution to the whole problem, that's all fine and dandy, but my actual questions are:

What does it mean to be uniformly continuous on an LCA group?

What is an approximation to the identity on an LCA group?

I'm unsure of these definitions basically because $G$ may not be a metric space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the definition I've ended up working with is:

$f$ is uniformly continuous on an LCA group $G$ if for each $\epsilon > 0$ we can pick a neighborhood $U$ of the identity such that $x- y \in U$ implies $|f(x) - f(y)|< \epsilon$.

As of right now I'm using Uryssohn lemma functions, possibly normalized in $L^1(G, \mu)$ norm, to be approximations to the identity.